# Postfix / PHP Mail() sends email as same email address, ignores header $from

Tags: php, email, header, postfix-mta

We recently upgraded our webserver and one of the first issues we came across was having problems sending to the same domain because the website was hosted on a different server to the company's exchange server.  Anyway I fixed that it was some simple config changes and disabling the mail service for the domain.

Anyway, that's not working but what I didn't notice at the time when I was testing some PHP mail forms on the website was that they are all getting sent as my email address to the client.

This is the PHP (Which I don't think is a problem)

```
<?php
    ini_set("sendmail_from", "noreply@******.com"); 

    $name       = $_POST['name'];
    $email      = $_POST['email'];
    $phone      = $_POST['phone'];
    $comments   = $_POST['comments'];
    $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    $recipient  = '*****@******.com';
    $subject    = "Comments submitted from the Contact Us form on www.wavesfm.com from $name" ;

    $message   = "This is an email submitted from the Contact Us form on the website www.*****.com containing details from $name \n";
    $message  .= "    \n";
    $message  .= "Name: $name \n";
    $message  .= "Email: $email \n";
    $message  .= "Phone Number: $phone \n";
    $message  .= "Comments: $comments \n\n\n";
    $message  .= "IP Address: $ip ";

    $headers   = "From: noreply@********.com \n";
    $headers  .= "Reply-To: $email";

    mail($recipient,$subject,$message,$headers);
    header( 'Location: http://www.*****.com/thanks.php' ) ; 
?>
```

Can anyone see any issues with that code? I have tried adding -fnoreply@****.com as a send parameter but it wont change my own email address from appearing as the sender.

I don't think this is a PHP issue it seems more like a Postfix issue, but whats really bothering me is how my email address which isn't used anywhere is appearing as the sender.

Has anyone had experience with this before? as before 2 weeks ago I hadn't used Postfix at all so its all rather new to me.

Web Server: Cent OS, Plesk 11.0.9

Mail Server: MS Exchange Mail Server / Using ORF

Postfix Log for one of the email's

Mar 27 13:48:41 dedicated postfix/pickup[12199]: 652EFA106C5: uid=48 from=
Mar 27 13:48:41 dedicated postfix/cleanup[14376]: 652EFA106C5: message-id=<20130327134841.652EFA106C5@dedicated.mydomain.com>
Mar 27 13:48:41 dedicated postfix/qmgr[12198]: 652EFA106C5: from=, size=726, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Mar 27 13:48:41 dedicated postfix/smtp[14378]: certificate verification failed for mail.mydomain.com[82.888.888.51]:25: untrusted issuer /CN=clientdomain-WAV01-CA
Mar 27 13:48:42 dedicated postfix/smtp[14378]: 652EFA106C5: to=, relay=mail.client_website.com[82.888.888.51]:25, delay=0.89, delays=0.04/0.01/0.36/0.48, dsn=2.6.0, status=sent (250 2.6.0 <20130327134841.652EFA106C5@dedicated.mydomain.com> [InternalId=11846] Queued mail for delivery)
Mar 27 13:48:42 dedicated postfix/qmgr[12198]: 652EFA106C5: removed

Answer (score 2):

There might be some string concatenation issues with the following code:

```
$headers = "From: noreply@********.com \n";
```

try

```
$headers = "From: noreply@********.com \r\n";
```

I recommend using phpmailer class for sending emails which is widely used:
https://github.com/Synchro/PHPMailer

Comment: +1 for pointing out the correct line split sequence. Defined here: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2821.txt

Comment: +1 for recommending phpMailer. I really don't understand why so many people keep using PHP's horrible built-in `mail()` function when alternatives like phpMailer exist and make life so much easier.

Comment: That didn't change anything, one important thing I should mention is its not only the "from" field that's appearing as my email its also the reply to as well which is weird. But also no idea where its getting my email address from because I didn't set the web server up I was logged in as root and my email isn't inputted in the server anywhere its like it somehow remembers it without me telling the server my email I am utterly stumped. We haven't implemented a PHP mail class because the website is ancient and they don't want to pay for work.

Comment: I used to use mail() too, when I found out about phpmailer it was love at first sight. Solves all of the issues like the one above.

Comment: Weird in the Postfix log my email is there so its definitely getting it from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The php.ini [sendmail_from](http://php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php) directive only really applies on windows boxes

> sendmail_from string Which "From:" mail address should be used in mail
>   sent from PHP under Windows. This directive also sets the
>   "Return-Path:" header.

I don't think it's a code issue as such.  Which user are you running the webserver+php environment from on your Linux box?  If you're running it as yourself then it's probably submitting to postfix using your email address.

Don't forget to tail /var/log/maillog if you're using postfix, that can tell you a lot and help you get to the bottom of the issue.

`sudo tail -f /var/log/maillog`

You could try signing up for a free account with [Sendgrid](http://sendgrid.com/) and coupled with PHPMailer, [Zend Mailer](http://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/zend.html) or Symfony Mailer libraries use that to send the emails and see if you get the same issue.